# Assignment only on changed object

Tags: c++

Basically I want to do this:

```
Object obj;
while (app->running)
    obj = update(obj)
```

Where update is a function that under some circumstances returns a new Object, and in others returns the same object, unchanged:

```
Object update(const Object& obj) {
    if (something)
        return Object{/*params*/};
    else
        return obj;
```

My question is how do I make `Object` do all the copy assignment operations ONLY IF returning the new object, but don't perform any operations when returning the initial `obj`?

Comment: Why not use `void update(Object& obj);`

Comment: I concur with @EdHeal. The only sensible solution is to change the design.

Comment: @EdHeal Because I'm trying to keep my functions pure, and trying to avoid self mutating state.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to enable moves for your `Object` class and move your object in and out of the `update` function.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like `void update(Object& obj)`, as others have mentioned, or preferably a member `update` function that you can call on any object.

```
class Object {
public:
    //other stuff
    bool update() {
        if (something) {
            //update stuff
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Note that checking for self assignment in `operator=` and returning a reference from `Object& update(const Object& obj)` does not work, due to a dangling reference when returning a new Object.

Comment: Beacuse OP returns an instance of Object class from `update`.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, I've updated the signature of update to return a reference. I think if he returns a new instance then there is a problem, because it gets destroyed and invalidates the reference, right?

Comment: You do not provide your 'updated' version of `update` anywhere in your answer.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes I do? Second line: "and have Object& update(const Object& obj)". I only wrote the signature and not the body, because the body would be the same.

Comment: If you change the signature the way you want it changed but leave the body the same, you end up with a dangling reference.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, as I suspected above. I've thus changed my answer, thanks.

Comment: with new edit your answer becomes a duplicate of already provided, so you might as well remove it.